# difference between infix operator and compound assignment operator in r

Tags: r, operators, pipeline

I wanted to see the difference between infix operator and compound assignment operator in r . So I used this example. This example may not be a good choice.

```
library("magrittr", lib.loc="~/R/R-3.5.1/library")    
x <- rnorm(10)
    x

    bb=x %<>% abs%>% sort

    bb1=x %>% abs %>% sort
```

But seems like i am getting the same answer in both cases. 
Is there any unique uses of compound assignment operator ??

Thank you

Comment: which package are you using? `tidyr`? Base R doesn't deal with that kind of operators.

Comment: @Nakx I used magrittr package. i added that to the code